# What is the apache setting to interrupt php after a specific time?

Tags: php, apache, timeout

On my linux box I want to simulate a timeout. I need the apache setting which tells php (running as a module) to terminate after a certain time (say 300 seconds).

I tried TimeOut in httpd.conf, but this doesn't work.

The reason is, there are many hosters who constrain the runtimes of php scripts to 300 seconds for example. I need to simulate this, but I don't know which setting it is (can't find any information about this).

set_time_limit() in php or max_execution_time in php.ini are not what I seek, because they are overwritten by this ominous apache setting.

Or maybe it is a setting in the OS?

Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule php5_module>

php_admin_value max_execution_time 1

</IfModule>
```

Try the above, just put it into your http.conf and change php5_module string to unix one mod_php4.c, mod_php5.c or whatever, but there are other ways (or patches) to prevent incresing the limits, like editing php source or apache source.

> php_admin_value name value
>
> Sets the value of the specified directive. This can not be used in
>   .htaccess files. Any directive type set with php_admin_value can not
>   be overridden by .htaccess or ini_set(). To clear a previously set
>   value use none as the value.
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Comment: Ok thanks, this seems to work, but in the end it's the same setting I can set in php, only that it can't be overriden, right?

Comment: Yes, you can only override it if you have access to http.conf